# Rewrite custom taxonomy URL

Tags: url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a custom taxonomy URL, here is my taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('cpt_category', array('cpt'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'labels' => $cpt_labels,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-slug/child-slug/', 'with_front' => true)
));
```

I want to add custom slugs to URL:

```
http://example.com/custom-slug/child-slug/cpt_category
```

I have added my rewrite rule but it is not working, also flushed rewrite rule, still I am getting error 404.

Comment: what happens if you remove the trailing `/` from the slug?

Comment: nothing.. same error 404

Comment: I mean in the slug argument of register taxonomy, it should be `custom-slug/child-slug`. and what do you mean added your rewrite rule? have you added a rule in addition to setting the slug argument?

Comment: yes I mean that. No I have not added any extra rules. Kindly help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: do you register your taxonomy on `init` action?

Comment: yes I did it. My taxonomy is appearing. and working fine. But when I rewrite it then it gives error 404